# magento certified developer exam passed but profile is not updated

Tags: certification

I have passed the exam for magento certified developer but my profile is not yet updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you took the exam most probably you received an exam score report on which is written that:

> Your testing results will be updated to your Magento account within 24-48 business hours after you have completed the exam.

Now are holidays, so don't worry, just wait. :)